# Neo4j browser not working in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, neo4j

Have not been able to use Chrome (Version 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit)) as a neo4j browser client after upgrading to the latest XCode / Command Tools in MacOS Yosemite 10.10.3 . Safari is working fine though. Is there an easy way to pinpoint to the actual problem? I'm using Neo4j 2.2.1

The following is a screenshot from the JavaScript console showing the errors:

[image: JavaScript console screenshot]

mostly load resource errors and an uncaught error failing to instatiate module neo4jApp .

It works fine under Safari. It also works in a Chrome Incognito Window. Partially resetting settings is a trial and error exercise. While resetting **all** chrome settings finally solved the initial problem, I wonder if there is a better way and not having to lose all other user settings in Chrome.

Comment: I have a latest version of Chrome (Version 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit)), Command Line Tools and Yosemite (10.10.3).

How is that problem looks like? Could you please post screenshot?

Or you can try to open Developer Tools in Chrome and there will be some javascript exception, which can be helpful.

Comment: updated the question with a screenshot showing the javascript console errors.

Comment: I suggest to clear cache and all additional data, which are related to neo4j console, from Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, @MicTech. This seemed to do the job however I wonder if there is another way not so drastic.

Comment: did you try shift+reload?

Comment: @ErnestoE You could click the Network tab and click the "Disable cache" checkbox and then reload with the inspector open (this jus disables cache while the inspector is open).

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHunger and Oskar, didn't try shift-reload nor the network option. Given that I solved the issue the hard way, this will hopefully guide other users who might have similar problems. Curiously enough, I noticed Ghostery asking about blocking the user experience program site, so I hope this was not related to that.

Comment: Hello again. Looking at the **Release Notes** in version 2.2.2, I wonder if the one: 'Resolves an issue that prevented the Neo4j Browser from loading in the latest Chrome release (43.0.2357.65)' might have been related to my case, although different version.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same exact issue today with Chromium 43.0.2357.81 (64-bit) and Neo4j 2.2.1. Clearing the cache and refreshing http://localhost:7474/browser/ wasn't working for me (javascript errors). What did work for me, was going to http://localhost:7474/webadmin/ which asked me to re-authenticate. After logging in, the Neo4j browser site loaded.